# Sort a PHP Array table by date

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a multi-columns HTML table generated by PHP with Array, taking data from a table in a database which contains a list of entries. One of the 5 columns is a datestamp. I would like **the HTML table to be sorted *by timestamp***, without any code it sorts it by ID (column0).

Here is the code I have to sort:

```
$table .= "<tr><td>" . $column0[$i][0] ."</td><td>" . $column1[$i][1] . "</td><td>" . $column2[$i][2] . "</td><td>" . $column3[$i][3] . "</td><td>" . $column4[$i][4] . "</td><td>" . $column5[$i][5] . "</td></tr>";
```

`$column5[$i][5]` is the one containing the datestamp. I've tried sort(), asort(), array_multisort()... without any luck.

Here is the SQL table structure:

```
column0: id
column1: number1
column2: text1
column3: number2
column4: text2
column5: date (format: Y-m-d H:m:s)
```

And here is an example of its content, for which I need to sort by the column date:

---

id.....number1.....text1.....number2.....text2................date

1........75.............toto..........58...........tata.......2014-04-07 16:43:51
2........34.............tutu..........07...........titi.........2013-04-09 08:27:34
3........83.............tyty..........53...........tete.......2015-04-08 12:36:18

---

Thank you!

Comment: Post your full codes!

Comment: If you are getting your data from a database, why don't you order it when you select it, rather than in you php? ie. `SELECT ... ORDER BY datestamp`

Comment: What else do you need? The rest is just some checking if the table is not empty, this is the only part concerning the table itself. There's just a `return $table;` after this.

Comment: In fact I'm modifying a file I didn't make, just to add the sorting, and I don't see any SQL query anywhere I could change to order by datestamp.

Comment: @Orphal we need to see you array structure. why not you posted that? how can drive a car except fuel?

Comment: If you mean an array structure just like your example, like `0 => array('id'=>1,'date'=>'2014-09-17'),`, there is no such thing anywhere. As I said, the arrays are made by taking the data in a database. `$column0[$i][x]` in my first post are the arrays. I edited my first post with some data from the table, if it helps understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `usort()` and compare date by `strtotime()`. An example here..

```
$arr = array(
    0 => array('id'=>1,'number1'=>'75','text1'=>'toto','number2'=>'58','text2'=>'tata','date'=>'2014-04-07 16:43:51',),
    1 => array('id'=>2,'number1'=>'34','text1'=>'tutu','number2'=>'07','text2'=>'titi','date'=>'2013-04-09 08:27:34',),
    2 => array('id'=>3,'number1'=>'83','text1'=>'tyty','number2'=>'53','text2'=>'tete','date'=>'2015-04-08 12:36:18',),
);

function sort_by_date($a, $b) {
    $a = strtotime($a['date']);
    $b = strtotime($b['date']);
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($arr, 'sort_by_date');

$keys = array_keys(current($arr));

$html = '<table border="1"><tr>';
foreach($keys as $key){
    $html .= '<th>'.$key.'</th>';
}
$html .= '</tr>';

foreach($arr as $value){
    $html .= '<tr>';
    foreach($value as $val){
        $html .= '<td>'.$val.'</td>';
    }
    $html .= '</tr>';
}
$html .= '</table>';
echo $html;
```

---

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My problem is that the data is not done with something like `0 => array('id'=>1,'number1'=>'75','text1'=>'toto','number2'=>'58','text2'=>'tata','date'=>'2014-04-07 16:43:51',),` it takes the data in a database which is filled with new entries from time to time. Arrays are not hard coded as you did in the first few lines. So how to adapt what you did with what I have (first post, first line of code)? I'm completely novice at PHP...

Comment: Okay, today a friend worked from your code, and implemented the working solution. Basically he just used your `function sort_by_date($a, $b) {...}` and `usort($column, 'sort_by_date');` and that's it. Thank you for your help!