# HTML PHP : List rows by most recent timestamp in a table

Tags: php, html, html-table

I have created an HTML table that reads and lists files from a directory using PHP. These files have timestamps in their filename (they have automatically uploaded recordings from a game server if it helps). I've formatted these timestamps so it prints/echos them according to this format, e.g:
" 2018-04-29 20:45 "

Currently, all rows are now listed in a random order. It makes it very confusing because it's essential for many to know which files are the most recent. I want the most recent item/timestamp to be listed at the top. How do I do this in the simplest and efficient way? I've browsed StackOverflow and only managed to find questions that focus on SQL listing.

Here's a part of the code:

```
<tbody>
 <?php

    */Bunch of declaring, specifying paths etc, taking parts of strings, nothing related to the issue*/

    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false) {

    */Bunch of declaring, specifying paths etc, taking parts of strings, nothing related to the issue*/
}

    if($file != "." && $file != "download.svg" && $file != ".." && $file != "index.php" && $file != ".htaccess" && $file != "Logo.png" && $file != "error_log" && $file != "cgi-bin") {

        echo "<tr class='pure-table-odd'>
                <td>$i</td>
                <td>$date3 $timestamp3</td>
                <td>$map</td>
                <td>$demosize</td>
                <td>
                <a href='$dlpath/$file'><img class='download' src='download.svg' alt='Download'></a>
                </td>
                </tr>";

        $i++;
    }
}
closedir($dh);

?>
</tbody>
```

Some clarification: It makes a new row for each file listed (.dem files)

[image]

EDIT: ***Someone mentioned to used scandir(), but I'm clueless how to adapt that to the code. Still bit of a novice when it comes to php***

Comment: Side note: Is there a reason why you're not using a database for this? It'd be a lot easier than using files, believe me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort a PHP Array table by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25951034/sort-a-php-array-table-by-date)

Comment: Use a [bootstrap Datatable](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4)

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I'd have to rewrite some parts on the back-end area. I could yes but it's a hassle. I'd much prefer if there was a simpler way of achieving this. Someone mentioned to used scandir(), but I'm clueless how to adapt that to the code. Still bit of a novice when it comes to php

Comment: @ashawe Thank you ashawe! I went with that.

Comment: @rickdev It would be great if you marked my answer as correct. Here at stackoverflow we appreciate your thank you but we generally do that by upvoting or marking it as a correct answer. Additionally, never post an answer appreciating another's answer. Use comments for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript to do this task like calling a javascript function to sort (as shown [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sort_table.asp)), but that's too tedious task.

A better way to sort the table is to use an external resource which already provides us this feature.

Use a [bootstrap Datatable](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4)

Click on the link, it provides an explanation with example.

Answer (score 0):

I'll go with the help I received from @ashawe in the comments section.

" Use a [bootstrap Datatable](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4) – @ashawe  "

Started using that, works very well. Thanks!